# C programming How to delete nodes of a linked list with a certain value

Tags: c

I have exams next week and I need your help with some parts I don't understand, I need to know how to delete the first occurrence and all occurrences of node having a specific value.
For example if this is the list "2-0-1-0-4" and the value is "0", the list becomes "2-1-0-4" for the first case and "2-1-4" for the second thanks.
this is the code I'm practicing with :
edit : Please include the first and last nodes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list *next;
};

void printlist(struct list* first)
{
    while (first != NULL) {
        printf(" %d ", first->data);
        first = first->next;
    }
}

struct list *addb(struct list *first)
{int d;
    struct list *ptr=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    printf("Enter data for the first node : ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    ptr->data=d;
    ptr->next=first;
    first=ptr;
    return first;
};

struct list *addl(struct list *first)
{int d;
    struct list *ptr;
    struct list *temp=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    printf("Enter data for the last node : ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    temp->data=d;
    temp->next=NULL;

    if(first == NULL)
        return temp;
    else
    {
        ptr=first;
        while(ptr->next != NULL)
            ptr = ptr->next;
        ptr->next = temp;
        return first;
    }


};

struct list *delf(struct list *first)
{
    if(first == NULL)
        printf("\nThe list is already empty");
    else
    {
        struct list *temp = first;
        first = first -> next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return first;
};

struct list *dell(struct list *first)
{
    struct list *temp = first;
    struct list *ptr = first;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    ptr->next = NULL;
    free(temp);
    temp = NULL;
    return first;
};



int main()
{ struct list *first = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
  printf("Enter data : ");
  scanf("%d",&first->data);

  struct list *second = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
  printf("Enter data : ");
  scanf("%d",&second->data);

  struct list *third = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
  printf("Enter data : ");
  scanf("%d",&third->data);

  struct list *fourth = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
  printf("Enter data : ");
  scanf("%d",&fourth->data);

  first->next = second;
  second->next = third;
  third->next = fourth;
  fourth->next = NULL;

  first=addb(first);
  first=addl(first);
  first=delf(first);
  first=dell(first);
  printlist(first);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you can find a lot of examples if you try to search for it. Anyway if you have an exam tomorrow you need to be able to do it by yourself, right?

Comment: Hi Rosalyo! Could you be more specific what is not working? Could you provide a smaller code example of your problem?

Comment: Hi Olov the code is irrelevant here and it works as it should be it's just what I'm practicing with, the problem is i can't seem to create a function to delete node with specific values, i really need your help! Thanks.

Comment: @Rosalyo where is your problem ? to find the cell with the specific value ? to remove a cell from the list ? what is your proposal to do ? there are thousands examples of linked list usage here why to ask for one more ? you will not learn looking other doing, you will doing yourself ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try below code.
(also comment on your code, no need to have a ";" at the end of function def)

```
    struct list *delall(struct list *first, int val)
    {   
        struct list *temp = first;
        struct list *ptr = first;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {   
            if (temp->data == val) {
                if (temp == first) {
                   first = first->next;
                   free(temp);
                   temp=first;
                } else {
                   ptr->next = temp->next;
                   free(temp);
                   temp =  ptr->next;
                }
            } else {
                ptr=temp;
                temp=temp->next;
            }
        }
        return first;
    }


    struct list *delone(struct list *first, int val)
    {   
        struct list *temp = first;
        struct list *ptr = first;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {   
            if (temp->data == val) {
                if (temp == first) {
                   first = first->next;
                   free(temp);
                   temp=first;
                   break;
                } else {
                   ptr->next = temp->next;
                   free(temp);
                   temp =  ptr->next;
                   break;
                }
            } else {
                ptr=temp;
                temp=temp->next;
            }
        }
        return first;
    }
```

Comment: You have no idea how much I've been looking and how much you have helped me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

So, no one here will do the homework for you but what we can do is give you a little help with it. Analysing the problem, you have a list defined by the following struct:

```c
struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list *next;
};
```

What you want in the first case is to find the first node where value stored in the node is the same as the value you want to remove, in code:

```c
if(node->data==value)
//remove node from list
```

to find this node it seems pretty straight forward that you have to iterate along all the nodes until you reach said value or you reach the end of the list:

```c
while(node!=NULL)
{
  if(node->data==value)
  {
    //remove node from list
    break;
  }
  node=node->next;
}
```

to remove the node from the list you need to keep the integrity of the list and free the allocated space.
To keep the integrity, take this list for example, A->B->C, if you want to remove B, you need to link A to C, A->C, otherwise your list would be broken. For that is is usually used an auxiliary variable to keep the previous record of the previous node to link it to the next if needed. In code:

```c
while(node!=NULL)
{
  struct list *prev=NULL;

  if(node->data==value)
  {
    prev->next=node->next;
    free(node);
    break;
  }

  prev=node;
  node=node->next;
}
```

Finally, you need to be careful when removing the first node, but I will keep that as a challenge for you ;).

With this function done I am sure you can done the second function easily. Good ludk for the exam.

Comment: Thanks for your help, just a quick note it's not homework it's just me reviewing and preparing for the exams